# rtag suggestion

Tags: discussion, tags

I feel like we should sort out tags related to graphics. Right now there tags
[visualization](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization), [plotting](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting), [figure-explanation](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figure-explanation) + tool/package specific like [ggplot2](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ggplot2).

I identify three distinct problems related to graphics:

- how to visualize `<my data>`? -> philosophical problem
- how can I reproduce figure of somebody else? -> coding/crafting problem
- how to understand figure of somebody else? -> science interpretation problem

The last one has very clear tag (and I love it). But the first two are blended in [visualization](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization) and [plotting](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) tags.

I suggest to remove tag [plotting](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plotting) and add description that would correspond to following tag scheme:

- how to visualize `<my data>`? -> [visualization](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualization)
- how can I reproduce figure of somebody else? -> [figure-reproduction](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figure-reproduction)
- how to understand figure of somebody else? -> [figure-explanation](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figure-explanation)

Why do I care? I usually can not help with 1 and 3, but I really like to do 2 (especially if it's core-R graph).

Can you think of other topics related to graphics? Do you think these scheme would work? Huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went on and created the tag [figure-reproduction](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/figure-reproduction) (I found two questions that were candidates of this tag)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a good structured way of tagging. However, I know from my own experience when writing a question, tagging is the last part before submitting, and usually I quickly choose tags that first pop up into my mind. So if I had a question in one of your 3 categories, I would probably tag them with `plotting` or `visualization` anyway. Maybe I would add `R` as well. I think not many users will do a thorough research of finding the right and perfect `tag` for their question. That does not mean it wouldn't be meaningful to create these tags, but I expect many 'wrongly' tagged questions as a consequence.

Comment: This is a good point. I like when the related tags would have links to each other in the excerpt.

Comment: The auto fill function for tags now, only works to extend what you are typing. So for example if you type `vi`, you'll get `visualization`, `webservice`, and `Gviz`. It would be cool to see some related tags too.

Comment: @KamilSJaron That's what excerpts are for, to guide how to use tags. About this answer, I think we can can retag the question as they come, there are few questions, so I wouldn't expect we miss some questions.

Comment: @b.nota that could be a request to the DAG team for the whole SE